# How can I use a button with a keyboard open in xamarin (iOS)

Tags: xamarin, button, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, keyboard

I'm trying to do a chat page, so I have an entry and a button to send the message, both in a Absolute Layout in a Scroll View but when my keyboard is open, I can't click on my button, the keyboard close then I have to click again, I have another button on the top of my page to close the page who when I scroll on top work with the keyboard open, it's not coming from my functions in C#, both are working if I put them in top of my page. Do you have an idea where my problem could come? (same thing if I put a ImageButton instead of a Button)

```
<ImageButton x:Name="CloseBtn" Source="close.png" WidthRequest="25" TranslationX="352" TranslationY="30" Clicked="Close"></ImageButton>
<Entry x:Name="EntryChat" Text="" HeightRequest="45" TranslationX="25" WidthRequest="335" Completed="Chat" Placeholder="Saisissez votre message" BackgroundColor="#e9e9e9" TextColor="#8f8983" PlaceholderColor="#8f8983" TranslationY="650" />
<Button x:Name="Btn" CornerRadius="10"  BackgroundColor="#cecece" WidthRequest="70" HeightRequest="45" TranslationX="325" TranslationY="650"  Clicked="Chat"  ></Button>
```

Comment: There's several possible solutions, have you tried any of these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344485/xamarin-forms-keyboard-covers-entry-text-field-on-ios @Antoine21000 Let me know which one works for you

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I don't have this problem I already use a Scroll View and my entry isn't "visually" cover by my keyboard, so I don't think these can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Completed` in the Entry. Entered text can be accessed by reading the Text property, and the TextChanged and Completed events signal that the text has changed or been completed.

```
<Entry x:Name="entry"
       Placeholder="Enter text"
       TextChanged="OnEntryTextChanged"
       Completed="OnEntryCompleted" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I already use Completed for the same function as my button, but my Button can still not be fired with my keyboard open, do you have an idea of what can I put in "OnEntryTextChanged" to make my Button usable ? (my app is for iOS)

Comment: You can use the `Completed` method instead of the button to control the message sending.

Comment: Yes, I already do that, but I would like to be able to use both.

Comment: You can change the absoluteLayout to verticalLayout or another layouts. It conflicted with the Scroll View.

Comment: Thanks that's work, it solved my problem.